# Windows equivalent to nmap

Tags: networking, command-line, ping, nmap, netstat

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655059/how-do-i-run-the-nmap-program-through-cygwin-in-windows/35837068#35837068) suggests `netstat` as an equivalent to `nmap` and also states that `nmap for windows` does not work.

But I use `nmap` for an specific purpose and that is to see if a port of a network is open or not like this:

```
nmap -p port ip
```

And I learnt this [command from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows equivalent to *nmap* is [*nmap*](https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html). You can download a pre-built installer, complete with the CLI tools and the Npcap driver needed for advanced scanning options.

The reason the answerer says nmap won't work on Windows is because that thread is using it for a *different purpose*: instead of scanning a remote system, they discuss scanning "localhost". This was not reliable on Windows (depending on which scan mode one used) because the loopback interface works differently there – but it does not apply to your question. Scanning remote devices works the same way on all systems.

For *only* checking whether a TCP port accepts connections or not, there exist various "netcat"-type tools: `nc.exe -v -v <host> <port>` from different sources; `plink.exe -v -raw -p <port> <host>` from PuTTY. They will either connect successfully or show an error message of some kind.

Comment: I googled netcat and the first search result was this https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/ turns out it's a fake upload packed with virus https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/49e16999db7bb33a58f949ef605020c52de4722582e83871481e7ad80ee19b86/detection and I found the original uploader https://sourceforge.net/projects/nc110/files/

Comment: Doesn't look fake to me. VirusTotal detects it as literally _netcat_ – because so many lazy malware authors tend to use it instead of writing their own code. (Note that there are five, maybe more, different implementations of netcat – some forks of the original, some fully independent like BSD netcat – so the "original" doesn't hold much.)

Comment: Of note: Nmap *can* scan localhost on Windows if Npcap is installed or if you use the `-sT` (TCP Connect scan) option. Also, Nmap comes with a Netcat replacement called Ncat.exe

Comment: plink.exe worked for me. Though the port parameter is passed with capital `-P`: `plink.exe -v -raw -P <port> <host>`